# Problema al usar `count()` en Eloquent con modelos *softdeleted*

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Estoy usando *softdelete* en todos los modelos.
Se plantea un caso en el que usar `count()` para everiguar el número de modelos relacionados no es correcto, cuando algunos de estos modelos se elimino y usa *softdelete*.

Me explico, tengo el modelo `Group` y el modelo `Option`, donde 1 "grupo" puede tener muchas "opciones" y una "opción" pertenecer a 1 único "grupo", la relación es 1-N y se traduce así:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Shop;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany as HasManyCollection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Group extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function options(): HasManyCollection
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Option::class); 
    }   
}


<?php

namespace App\Models\Shop;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo as BelongsToCollection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Group extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function group(): BelongsToCollection
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(OptionGroup::class);
    }  
}
```

En este caso `count()` funciona de forma correcta.

Si tengo 5 opciones para el grupo con ID 7 y ninguna fue eliminada:

```
Group::find(7)->options->count(); // 5
```

Si elimino 3 y repito la consulta:

```
Group::find(7)->options->count(); // 2
```

Esto según lo esperado, por defecto *Eloquent* no recupera los registros *trashed*.

***Ahora el problema***, los "grupos" de asocian a "productos" (modelo `Product`) donde 1 "producto" puede tener varios "grupos" asociados y un "grupo" estar relacionado con varios "productos", tengo pues una relación NN, que se resolvería en un sistema relacional con una tabla intermedia (`option_group_product`), en Eloquent los modelos serían:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Shop;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany as BelongsToManyCollection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany as HasManyCollection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Group extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function options(): HasManyCollection
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Option::class); 
    }

    public function products(): BelongsToManyCollection
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            OptionGroup::class,
            'option_group_product',
            'option_group_id',
            'product_id'
        );
    }
}


<?php

namespace App\Models\Shop;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany as BelongsToManyCollection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Product extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function optionGroups(): BelongsToManyCollection
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(
            OptionGroup::class,
            'option_group_product',
            'product_id',
            'option_group_id'
        )->orderBy('option_group_product.id');
    }
}
```

Y para la relación (sin softdelete):

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Shop;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class OptionGroupProduct extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'option_group_product';
}
```

Ahora si tengo un grupo, con ID 1 asociado a 5 productos:

```
OptionGroup::find(1)->products->count(); // 5
```

pero si elimino 3 productos (sofdeleted):

```
OptionGroup::find(1)->products->count(); // 5
```

En este caso `count()` cuenta los registros de la *tabla intermedia*,
sin tener en cuenta si los registros de la tabla `products` fueron o no *softdeleted*,
¿cómo obtengo el número de los registros "no eliminados"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu tabla pivote debiera extender de Pivot, no de Model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\ModelTraits\HasQueryCache;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class OptionGroupProduct extends Pivot
{

}
```

Y la relación de tipo HasAndBelongsToMany (que en Laravel se expresa con una doble belongsToMany)  debe terminar en la tabla objetivo, no puede terminar en el pivote.

Tu relación de Group a Producto sería entonces:

```
public function products(): BelongsToMany
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(
        Product::class,
        'option_group_product',
        'option_group_id',
        'product_id'
    )->using(OptionGroupProduct::class;
}
```